# Issue while using weighted regression (lm) with boot package in R

Tags: r, regression, lm

I am having issues passing arguments to the statistic (for which I have a function) using the boot function. Here is an example:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(faraway)
library(boot)
data(strongx)
g3 <- lm(crossx ~ energy, strongx, weights=rep(1, nrow(strongx)))

bootReg <- function(formulatostat, data, ind, weitostat) {
  weig <- weitostat[ind]
  fit <- lm(formula=formulatostat, data = data[ind, ], weights = weig)
  return(coef(fit))
}
wei <- rep(1, nrow(strongx))

bootResults <-
  boot(
    data = strongx,
    statistic = bootReg,
    R = 2000,
    formulatostat = crossx ~ energy,
    weitostat = wei)
```

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'weig' not found

Of course, my weights are 1 and so the weighted part is unnecessary. But the issue remains while using real weights as well. This is a demonstration of the problem I am having with another data. The boot function states: "Any further arguments can be passed to statistic through the ... argument." Seemingly, the formulatostat is getting passed to bootReg but not the weights bit. To compare without weights:

```
bootReg <- function(formulatostat, data, ind) {
  fit <- lm(formula=formulatostat, data = data[ind, ])
  return(coef(fit))
}
wei <- rep(1, nrow(strongx))

bootResults <-
  boot(
    data = strongx,
    statistic = bootReg,
    R = 2000,
    formulatostat = crossx ~ energy)
```

This works. Any advice on how to incorporate the weights would be appreciated.

Comment: This is off topic for this site.

Comment: Welcome to crossvalidated. See boot manual: "The first argument passed will always be the original data. The second will be a vector of indices, frequencies or weights which define the bootstrap sample." >> try switching the "data" and "ind" arguments to 1st and 2nd place in your functions. btw: this is not the right forum for debugging questions (statistical problems, so i guess this q will be deleted shortly) + you can increase your chances to get a good answer in the future if you provide running code (including example data). Cheers

Comment: Apologies. I posted on stats.stackexchange. How is this off topic? Sorry for my ignorance but this is my first time posting on here.

Comment: To mzunhammer, thanks. I tried your suggestion and it does not work. The example code that I put up actually is fully reproducible. The data on there is from the faraway package as it indicates.

Comment: Questions that are only about how R code works are generally off topic here.  This is a site for questions about statistics. Since this has a reproducible example, this should be on topic on [SO], which is a site about code. If you wait, we can try to migrate it for you.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification. Makes sense for organization, obviously. Thank you; if there is an automatic way to migrate it, that would be great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `stats::model.frame` function (which is being called within the `lm` function) is looking for a object named `weig` in the object given to the `data` argument, and in the parent environment in which the formula (`crossx ~ energy`) is defined.

There is no column named `weig` within the data.frame given to `data`. And since you have defined the formula `crossx ~ energy` outside the `bootReg` function, `lm` function is failing to find the `weig` object.

You can fix the error, either by adding the weights to the object given to the `data` argument, or by creating the formula object in the same environment as you are calling the `lm` function.

Solution 1:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(faraway)
library(boot)
data(strongx)
g3 <- lm(crossx ~ energy, strongx, weights=rep(1, nrow(strongx)))

bootReg <- function(formulatostat, data, ind, weitostat) {
  input_to_lm <- data[ind, ]
  input_to_lm$weig <- weitostat[ind]
  fit <- lm(formula=formulatostat, data = input_to_lm, weights = weig)
  return(coef(fit))
}
wei <- rep(1, nrow(strongx))

bootResults <-
  boot(
    data = strongx,
    statistic = bootReg,
    R = 2000,
    formulatostat = crossx ~ energy,
    weitostat = wei)
```

Solution 2:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(faraway)
library(boot)
data(strongx)
g3 <- lm(crossx ~ energy, strongx, weights=rep(1, nrow(strongx)))

bootReg <- function(formulatostat, data, ind, weitostat) {
  weig <- weitostat[ind]
  fit <- lm(formula=as.formula(formulatostat), data = data[ind, ], weights = weig)
  return(coef(fit))
}
wei <- rep(1, nrow(strongx))

bootResults <-
  boot(
    data = strongx,
    statistic = bootReg,
    R = 2000,
    formulatostat = 'crossx ~ energy',
    weitostat = wei)
```